# Initiating CSS Animation Only After Complete Page Load

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, svg, css-animations

i need a solution with Wordpress.
In my case, i want to CSS Animtations only effect after the page is 100% loaded.
An example:
[text](https://miro.com/ways-we-work/)

My HTML

```
 <div class="svg-one">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="467" height="195" viewBox="0 0 467 195" fill="none">
      <path
        d="M-5.68701 0.4375C-5.68701 0.4375 304.086 30.9591 314.874 120C323.963 194.797 466.079 194.745 466.079 194.745"
        stroke="#1A3D96" stroke-width="0.34" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="468" height="196" viewBox="0 0 468 196" fill="none">
      <path
        d="M-6.0835 1.08398C-6.0835 1.08398 294.147 28.6178 303.406 117.71C311.193 192.584 467.721 194.851 467.721 194.851"
        stroke="#1A3D96" stroke-width="0.34" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" />
    </svg>
  </div>
```

My CSS

```
@keyframes fade-in-left-to-right {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}


.svg-one {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    left: 0;
    top: 25%;
    width: 14%;
}

.svg-one svg {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 23vw;
    height: auto;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    animation: fade-in-left-to-right 2.5s linear forwards;
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
}


.svg-one svg:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
}

.svg-one svg:last-child {
    top: 70px;
}
```

Thanks for reading, have a great day!

A function let's animations run only after the website loaded

Comment: you'll need javascript to "react" to the page being "load"ed

Comment: Use JavaScript windows.onload to add for exemple the animation style to .svg-one svg

Answer (score 0):

Move your animation-related declarations into a separate style rule:

```
.svg-one.animate svg {
    animation: fade-in-left-to-right 2.5s linear forwards;
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
```

Then simply add the class `animate` to your wrapper element when the document has fully loaded:

```
addEventListener('load', evt => {
  document.querySelector('.svg-one').classList.add('animate')
})
```